# No output from for loop eventReactive: Shiny

Tags: for-loop, shiny

Awesome people out there! Need a quick help on Shiny `eventReactive()`.

I have two data frames (df1, df2), which are outputs of previous calculations in my Shiny app. I need to run a for loop on these two data frames in my Shiny app with `eventReactive()`. When I click/trigger the `actionButton("simulate")` from my UI. I need to run the below for loop and create a data table in Shiny app. The problem I have is I do not see anything happen on UI, UI is blank (while I expect to see a datatable) and there is no error message to debug.

The `for` loop runs fine in console but not in the Shiny App. I tried `lapply` but that did not work as well. It was also an empty screen without any output.

***Any help is much Appreciated!***

**For loop in console, this runs fine**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2018:2020), each = 12),
                  Treatment = rep(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), each = 4, times = 3),
                  Source = rep(c("Ran", "Ban", "Dam", "Sam"), times = 9),
                  Value = sample(36))

df2 <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2018:2020), each = 3),
                  Treatment = rep(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), times = 3),
                  Value2 = sample(9))

tnames <- unique(df1$Treatment)

simdata <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(tnames)){
  
  vcmp <- df1 %>% filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
    group_by(Source) %>% 
    summarise(median = median(Value)) %>%
    mutate(Trait  = tnames[i])
  
  preSD <- df2 %>% filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
    summarize(Value2 = median(Value2))
  
  simuS <- tibble(nLo = rep(5:15, times = 3), 
                  nRe = rep(1:3, each = 11),
                  nPlo = nLo * nRe, 
                  Vg = vcmp[[3,2]], 
                  Ve = vcmp[[4,2]],
                  ycept = preSD[[1,1]],
                  sm = sqrt(Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo),
                  sd = sqrt(2 * (Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo)),
                  ld = 2 * sd,
                  Rp = factor(nRe), 
                  Treatment = tnames[i])
  
  simdata <- rbind(simdata, simuS)
}
```

**MRE, Shiny implementation, I kind of solved half, I can see the output now but it only generates one iteration. not the entire for loop**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                 selectInput("Parameter", "Select Parameter","", ""),
                 actionButton("generate", "Generate Data"),
                 hr(),
                 hr(),
                 actionButton("simulate", "Simulate Data")),
    mainPanel(width = 7,
              DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("table2"),
              DT::dataTableOutput("table3"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  table1 <- eventReactive(input$generate,{
    df1 <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2018:2020), each = 12),
               Treatment = rep(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), each = 4, times = 3),
               Source = rep(c("Ran", "Ban", "Dam", "Sam"), times = 9),
               Value = sample(36))
  })
  
  table2 <- eventReactive(input$generate, {
    df2 <- data.frame(Year = rep(c(2018:2020), each = 3),
                      Treatment = rep(c("AA", "BB", "CC"), times = 3),
                      Value2 = sample(9))
  })
  
  simudata <- eventReactive(input$simulate,{
    tnames <- unique(table1()$Treatment)
    simudata <- tibble()
    
    for(i in 1:length(tnames)){
      
      vcmp <- table1() %>% 
        filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
        group_by(Source) %>% 
        summarise(median = median(Value)) %>%
        mutate(Trait  = tnames[i])
      
      preSD <- table2() %>% 
        filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
        summarize(Value2 = median(Value2))
      
      new_Row <- tibble(nLo = rep(5:15, times = 3),
                      nRe = rep(1:3, each = 11),
                      nPlo = nLo * nRe, 
                      Vg = vcmp[[3,2]], 
                      Ve = vcmp[[4,2]],
                      ycept = preSD[[1,1]],
                      sm = sqrt(Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo),
                      sd = sqrt(2 * (Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo)),
                      ld = 2 * sd,
                      Rp = factor(nRe), 
                      Treatment = tnames[i])
      
      simudata <- rbind(simudata, new_Row)
      return(simudata)
      }
    })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(table1(), options = list(paging = t, pageLength = 5))
  output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(table2(), options = list(paging = t, pageLength = 5))
  output$table3 <- DT::renderDataTable(simudata(), options = list(paging = t, pageLength = 5))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You have a better chance of getting help if you post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some sample data.

Comment: YBS, I have edited and added MRE. I was able to get the output printed but the output has only one iteration (column Treatment). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address your issue by using `local()` as shown below.

```
simudata <- eventReactive(input$simulate,{
    tnames <- unique(table1()$Treatment)
    simudata <- tibble()
    
    for(i in 1:length(tnames)){
      local({
        i <- i
        vcmp <- table1() %>% 
          dplyr::filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
          group_by(Source) %>% 
          dplyr::summarise(median = median(Value)) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(Trait  = tnames[i])
        
        preSD <- table2() %>% 
          dplyr::filter(Treatment == tnames[i]) %>%
          dplyr::summarize(Value2 = median(Value2))
        
        new_Row <- tibble(nLo = rep(5:15, times = 3),
                          nRe = rep(1:3, each = 11),
                          nPlo = nLo * nRe, 
                          Vg = vcmp[[3,2]], 
                          Ve = vcmp[[4,2]],
                          ycept = preSD[[1,1]],
                          sm = sqrt(Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo),
                          sd = sqrt(2 * (Vg / nLo + Ve / nPlo)),
                          ld = 2 * sd,
                          Rp = factor(nRe), 
                          Treatment = tnames[i])
        
        simudata <<- rbind(simudata, new_Row)
      })
      
    }
    return(simudata)
  })
```

Comment: YBS, this solution worked for me. Thank you. I have accepted the answer. 
Can you help me understand why to add local & what does it do please?

Comment: I think you should read up on `local()` and why it works. As shiny does lazy evaluation, your `i` has gone through the cycle and taken the last value.  That is the reason you only get one value. To avoid that, you can either use `lapply` or `local` within the `for` loop.